# PHPUnit and Woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, phpunit

I'm creating a plugin that should make sure that the user can have only one product at time in the cart so if a user add a product the plugin should empty it before adding.

My plugin use `woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation` filter and this is the function:

```
/**
     * Empty cart before add new item
     *
     * @param mixed $cart_item_data Cart item data.
     */
    public function woo_custom_add_to_cart_before($cart_item_data)
    {
        global $woocommerce;

        $woocommerce->cart->empty_cart();

        return true;
    }
```

I want to make sure that this works with a phpunit test:
NB: the test is not completed yet, I'm trying to use WC function before complete it

```
public function test_only_one_product_in_cart()
{
    activate_plugin('woocommerce/woocommerce.php');
    require_once WP_PLUGIN_DIR . '/woocommerce/woocommerce.php';

    $product_id = $this->factory->post->create(
        array(
            'post_type' => 'product'
        )
    );
    WC()->cart->add_to_cart($product_id);

    $cart_content = WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_count();

    $this->assertEquals(1, $cart_content);
}
```

If I run the test it says:

```
Error: Call to a member function add_to_cart() on null
```

How can I use Woocommerce function in a unit test?

Comment: It means cart wasn't initialized in WooCommerce Object, Try to track the result of is_request( 'frontend' ) inside init() function in class-woocommerce.php, as the request needs to be coming from frontend in order to make cart object to be initialized.

Comment: `is_request('frontend')` has a return of `(!is_admin() || defined('DOING_AJAX')) && !defined('DOING_CRON') && !$this->is_rest_api_request()`. The value of this expression is `true`

Comment: I've checked that the init function is not called during the test